# Is there any way to generate the apk by using any external JS bundle

Tags: bundle, react-native, react-native-ios

We will create some common reusable react native components and share it across multiple teams, Where they will build the apk along with their own project specific components.

is there any way like we can generate the JS bundle and ship it to all projects like a reference and include this bundle while generating the .apk or .ipa out of it

**Note:** We don't want to host the base components into NPM.

Is it possible to include the external Js bundle and generate the release build  Or id there any other way to achieve it in react native.?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but sounds logical to me for android on windows.

**Create bundle by**

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

and place the bundled file in respective directory

and for ios you can directly drag and drop bundle in xcode project.

Comment: This will generate the bundle file. But i want to use this bundle and add few new js components into that . Is there a way to do that .? so that i can genarate the apk including new components and existing bundle